# Solving nonlinear first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation

$$x^{2}y'{(x)} + 2xy{(x)} = y^{2}{(x)}$$

With initial condition $y{(1)} = 1$ and I want to solve this, by observation, we can see the LHS is $x^{2}y{(x)}$ but I am unfamiliar with tackling the RHS and was wondering where to go from here.

$$x^{2}y{(x)} = \int y^{2}{(x)} \ dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This suggests the change of unknown $z=x^2y$, leading to an equation in separeted variables.

Answer (score 2):

First, write the ode as

$$ x^{2}y'{(x)} + 2xy{(x)} = y^{2}{(x)} \implies y'+2\frac{y}{x}=\frac{y^2}{x^2}. $$

Now, use the change of variables $y=x u$ in the above ode which yields

$$ xu'+3u = u^2 \implies \int \frac{du}{u^2-3u} = \int \frac{dx}{x}. $$

I think you can finish it now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Julián's answer, note that the LHS is precisely the derivative of $x^2 y(x)$, which readily leads to the change of variables that he pointed out. Thus, you have:

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \left(\frac{z}{x^2}\right)^2,$$

which can now easily solved.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
x^{2}y'{(x)} + 2xy{(x)} = [x^2 y(x)]'
$$
Then
$$
[x^2 y(x)]' = y^{2}{(x)}
$$
Putting $z(x)=x^2 y(x)$, i.e. $z^2(x)/x^4=y^2(x)$, we have
$$
z'(x) = \frac{z^2(x)}{x^4}
$$
separable variables equation.

Comment: Although your solution did not get credits, I think it is the solution more natural since araises from $(x^2y)'=2xy+x^2y'$, which immediately separates variables.